# Intent to turn ON GPS and back to application

Tags: android, android-intent, gps

This code is able to go to GPS settings and turns it ON but on pressing back it does not intent back to application. Instead it takes me to the home of my launcher.

```
        public void createDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle(R.string.gps_message);
        alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.gps_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
                return;
            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                return;
            }
        });
        alert.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that creates the dialog please.

Comment: Check your logcat. It should be returning to your app but maybe your app has exited or crashed.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your start code to this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Also instead of calling return after it try changing it to this:

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Calling return might be closing your Activity.

Comment: :( can you post the code you're using to display your dialog and I'll see if I can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
AlertDialog.Builder notifyLocationServices = new AlertDialog.Builder(PlacesDecoder.this);
        notifyLocationServices.setTitle("Switch on Location Services");
        notifyLocationServices.setMessage("Location Services must be turned on to complete this action. Also please take note that if on a very weak network connection,  such as 'E' Mobile Data or 'Very weak Wifi-Connections' it may take even 15 mins to load. If on a very weak network connection as stated above, location returned to application may be null or nothing and cause the application to crash.");
        notifyLocationServices.setPositiveButton("Ok, Open Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent openLocationSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                PlacesDecoder.this.startActivity(openLocationSettings);
                finish();
            }
        });
        notifyLocationServices.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        notifyLocationServices.show();
```

note: change the values to suit yourself.
also know that this does not use start activity for result. so please modify them accordingly. eg: class name
I hope this helps